# Antlr v4: 'mismatched input'

Tags: powershell, compiler-errors, grammar, pascal, antlr4

Basically, I'm trying to run this Pascal program through Antlr 4 in Powershell.

```
PROGRAM AddTwoNumbers;

    VAR Num1, Num2, Sum : Integer;

BEGIN 
    Write('Input number 1:'); 
    Readln(Num1);
    Writeln('Input number 2:');
    Readln(Num2);
    Sum := Num1 + Num2; 
    Writeln(Sum);
    Readln;
    END.
```

However, I keep getting the following error in PowerShell:

```
line 8:4 mismatched input 'Writeln' expecting {'END', ';'}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my grammar file:

```
simpleStatement
    : assignmentStatement
    | procedureStatement
    | exitStatement
    | gotoStatement
    | emptyStatement
    | outputStatement
    | readKey
    ;

outputStatement
    : ( 'Writeln' | 'Write' ) LPAREN string RPAREN SEMI
    input
    ;

input
    : inputStatement
    | readKey
    ;

inputStatement
    : 'Readln' ( LPAREN identifier RPAREN )* SEMI
    ;

readKey
    : 'Readkey' SEMI
    ;
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: More info needed. How do you run it, give commands.

Comment: I'm not so sure those are the only *relevant parts of the grammar*. What does the grammar say about a series of `outputStatement` terms? The parser seems to have an issue with seeing a second one in the input stream.

Comment: Also provide full grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiles and runs perfectly in my machine. Have you tried compiling it using another compiler?